# PTIJ: Sarah's two lives

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In [Gen 23:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0123.htm#1), we read about Sarah's two lives.

> וַיִּהְיוּ חַיֵּי שָׂרָה מֵאָה שָׁנָה וְעֶשְׂרִים שָׁנָה וְשֶׁבַע שָׁנִים שְׁנֵי חַיֵּי שָׂרָה
>
> And Sarah's lives were 127 years long, Sarah's two lives.

We know from here that Sarah had two lives, each 127 years long.  During which of her two lives do the Torah's stories occur (*ie.* the first or the second), and what do we know about Sarah's other 127-year life?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I'd be interested in the serious answer too

Comment: @SAH See the linked translation.

Comment: Not clear how this answers?

Comment: @SAH Seriously: חיים is regularly plural, and שני here means "years of", not "two".

Answer (score 5):

The pasuk actually lists *three* of her lives, but then says she had only two!

> וַיִּהְיוּ חַיֵּי שָׂרָה מֵאָה שָׁנָה וְעֶשְׂרִים שָׁנָה וְשֶׁבַע שָׁנִים שְׁנֵי חַיֵּי שָׂרָה
>
> And Sarah's lives were 100 years, and 20 years, and 7 years, Sarah's two lives.

So now how do we split her three lives into two?

Since she was a righteous woman, it's reasonable to assume that she lived the maximum of [120 years](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/why-do-we-say-you-should-live-till-120). So one of her lives was 120 and the other was 7.

So what was her 7 year life?

We [learn](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3843/5151) that when a person converts, it is as if they are reborn. Clearly, Sarah converted at age 7. Converting at such a young age is what made her a suitable match for Avraham, who converted at [three years old](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112356/jewish/Abraham-Our-Father.htm).